# Sonarqube-Seeing Coverage-Can not find the detail information about unit tests

Tags: sonarqube

I'm using:
sonarqube 5.6.3
sonar-scanner 2.8
jacoco(reports produced by maven project)
junit
When I completed the analysis successfully, I open the sonar UI to view the coverage, I can not see the detail hint information(popup) about test file and covering test.
*This is the screenshot reference to* *http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONARQUBE56/Seeing+Coverage*

[image: official documentation view]

and *this is my analysis result screenshot,only display some words without any detail information*:

[image: my test view]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You can take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) first and learn [How to Ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example. It will be easier for us to help you.

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved this problem in modify maven configuration by adding listeners.